# How to format a number with + and - sign in Delphi

Tags: delphi, numbers, string-formatting

Using Delphi, is there a way to enforce sign output when using the Format function on integers? For positive numbers a '+' (plus) prefix shall be used, for negative numbers a '-' (minus) prefix. The handling of Zero is not important in my case (can have either sign prefix or none).

I would like to avoid using format helper functions for each format and if-then-else solutions.

Comment: You are out of luck. The `Format` function has no such capability.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Like [David already commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11291960/how-to-format-a-number-with-and-sign-in-delphi#comment14854553_11291960), the [`Format`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.SysUtils.Format#Format_Strings) function offers no format specifier to that purpose.

If you really want a single-line solution, then I suppose you could use something like:

```
uses
  Math;
const
  Signs: array[TValueSign] of String = ('', '', '+');
var
  I: Integer;
begin
  I := 100;
  Label1.Caption := Format('%s%d', [Signs[Sign(I)], I]);  // Output: +100
  I := -100;
  Label2.Caption := Format('%s%d', [Signs[Sign(I)], I]);  // Output: -100
```

But I would prefer making a separate (library) routine:

```
function FormatInt(Value: Integer): String;
begin
  if Value > 0 then
    Result := '+' + IntToStr(Value)
  else
    Result := IntToStr(Value);
end;
```

Comment: Thanks for the work-around with Sign() and Abs(). I searched for a one-line solution because I wanted to keep the ability to specify amount of leading zeros, etc. with the format string.

Comment: Rather than calling `Abs`, which gives unexpected results when the input is -2147483648, just add the `+` to positive values and use the default output for non-positive values. So, set `Signs = ('', '', '+')` and then use `Format('%s%d', [Signs[Sign(I)], I])`.

Comment: Nice solution +1. To make digits aligned and to see it clearly I prefer to use space ' ' instead of plus '+'.